# How are Linux permissions handled when moving a drive between computers?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, security

I have a dual-boot between Windows 7 and Ubuntu with multiple hard drives and — other than the Linux install partitions — all of my other partitions are NTFS. I plan to replace most of these with EXT3 or EXT4 partitions as I redo my W7 as a *gaming-only system* and use everything else in Linux. How does the security and permissions work if I need to move EXT3/4 drives between multiple Linux systems, or if I need to reinstall Linux for some reason?

Let's say I have...

1. a 1TB ext3 drive (docs and movies) on computer Linux01
2. 6 months down the road I build a COMPLETELY new system (Linux02)
3. Will I have to do anything special in order for Linux02 to have full read/write access to the drive pulled from Linux01?

How does the above change if I used full-disk encryption on the 1TB drive?

I hope I explained myself well enough. :)
I've wanted to ask this question for, literally, years! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux permissions (for owner, group, world) are driven by the user ID and the group ID.  If you set up your new system with the same UIDs and GIDs (the two numbers following the "x" in the password field in /etc/passwd) You should be able to move the disks between systems without problem.

As for encryption, depends upon how you do that.  Do you have the encryption key yourself, or does the encryption software generate some of the key on the fly based on some system configuration?  If you control the key, no problem moving disks.  If not, maybe that encryption is designed to prevent easily moving disks.